# Loading an Image in Java/Gdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been developing an android game for a while now and i have this problem. Let's take this example code

```
class game {


   private Texture image;

   public game()
   {
       image = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png");     
   }
}
```

If i write my code like this everything is fine, the image loads properly and the game runs smoothly.

The problems start when i try to create a folder inside my assets folder and load the image from there.

For example

```
class game {


   private Texture image;

   public game()
   {
       image = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("newfolder/image.png");     
   }
}
```

When i do this and compile it i get no erros inside Eclipse and everything is fine. But when i try to export the project into a runnable deskop jar or as an android application, the game start for a second, shows a black screen then it stops. On android it doesn't even start. I believe it is not able to locate and load the image and throws an exception.

Any idea why this is happening and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you export your executable in Eclipse you need to package the required assets into the jar.

Often times when you export a JAR file it doesn't include the added library folders, and it searches for an external folder wherever the JAR is located.

Try checking the option for packing required assets into the JAR. This will actually put the assets inside the JAR file and make the necessary changes to the manifest.

I would also double check the LibGDX wiki and make sure that your projects build paths are properly configured to use assets folder from the android project.